# android sdk cannot create project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

has anyone seen an error like this, when building workspace, even when creating projects??

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'egajkgb'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'ub'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is all that i see when i make a project. any tips on getting rid of this? im so sure ive looked everywhere for this, cant find an answer to it

EXTRA:
my updater doesnt work either, no idea if thats related. the error for that is:
"Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.

```
Error while reading from repository: download.eclipse/releases/juno/site.xml.
Error while reading from repository: dl-ssl.google/android/eclipse/site.xml.
Error while reading from repository: download.eclipse/eclipse/updates/4.2/site.xml."
```

any help would be much appreciated

cheers,

--EDiT--
the links above don't work cos im new so deleted the ".com"

--EDIT 2--
i downloaded the whole ADT bundle and am working with eclipse. have tried on various ADT bundles, namely 130514 and 130522, which give the same error. 1302** just does not give an error at all, rather it does nothing when clicking finish

help appreciated guys!

Comment: just update ur eclipse?

Comment: @Sam thanks, unfortunately i cannot even update because of those other warnings. really weird problem i have, not sure if something else in the back end is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer directly to your problem, but it may help you anyway.
Sometimes eclipse just crashes (and so does the android sdk).
You may just remove any eclipse files and download the complete sdk again.
Since eclipse does not need to be installed/uninstalled this usually solves all those problems.
If you still got problems with your new downloaded sdk you have to look in your "document and settings" folder .. or however it is called. Eclipse stores some settings in your user-folder.
Delete those settings too

Comment: thanks bud, will look into that. deleted all possible hidden metadata folders etc, still giving problems... even tried shifting the workspace elsewhere. done multiple reinstallations, unfortunately to no avail

cheers,